# Why can't javascript not register getSignedUrl() (cloud functions)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, image-resizing

Can someone please help me figure out when javascript cannot seem to find the getSignedUrl() . I am attempt to recreate my own version of generateThumbnail (https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/generate-thumbnail/functions/index.js) and storage-resize-images (https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/storage-resize-images/functions/lib/index.js) for some reason it cannot find the function even though imported the correct library.
Here is the error I am receiving:
Error when resizing image TypeError:
updatedImage.getSignedUrl is not a function
at /workspace/index.js:121:22
at Array.forEach ()
at /workspace/index.js:120:17
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

Here is my code for reference:

```js
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: "./cloud",
});
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
//const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp");
const sharp = require("sharp");
const resize_image_1 = require("./resize-images");
const config_1 = require("./config");
const logs = require("./logs");
const util_1 = require("./util");
const {constants } = require("buffer");

// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize ( async (object) => {
      logs.start();
      const { contentType } = object; // This is the image MIME type
      const tmpFilePath = path.resolve("/", path.dirname(object.name)); // Absolute path to dirname

      const feedPath = '/uploads/groups/*/feed'; 

      if (!contentType) {
          logs.noContentType();
          return;
      }
      if (!contentType.startsWith("image/")) {
          logs.contentTypeInvalid(contentType);
          return;
      }
      if (object.contentEncoding === "gzip") {
          logs.gzipContentEncoding();
          return;
      }
      if (config_1.paramToArray(feedPath) &&
          !util_1.startsWithArray(feedPath, tmpFilePath)) {
          logs.imageOutsideOfPaths(feedPath, tmpFilePath);
          return;
      }
      
      if (object.metadata && object.metadata.resizedImage === "true") {
          logs.imageAlreadyResized();
          return;
      }

      const bucket = storage.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
      const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
      const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
      console.log("File path :" +filePath);
      const fileExtension = path.extname(filePath);
      console.log("File extension :" +fileExtension);
      const fileNameWithoutExtension = util_1.extractFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath, fileExtension);
      const objectMetadata = object;
      let originalFile;
      let remoteFile;

      try {
        originalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
        const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(originalFile);
        // Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.
        logs.tempDirectoryCreating(tempLocalDir);
        await mkdirp(tempLocalDir);
        logs.tempDirectoryCreated(tempLocalDir);
        // Download file from bucket.
        remoteFile = bucket.file(filePath);
        logs.imageDownloading(filePath);
        await remoteFile.download({ destination: originalFile });
        logs.imageDownloaded(filePath, originalFile);
        // Get a unique list of image types
        const imageTypes = new Set(['jpeg']);
        // Convert to a set to remove any duplicate sizes
        const imageSizes = new Set(['480x480','640x640','1024x1024']);
        const tasks = [];
        console.log("ileNameWithoutExtension : " +fileNameWithoutExtension);
        console.log("fileExtension : " +fileExtension);
        imageTypes.forEach((format) => {
            imageSizes.forEach((size) => {
                tasks.push(resize_image_1.modifyImage({
                    bucket,
                    originalFile,
                    fileDir,
                    fileNameWithoutExtension,
                    fileExtension,
                    contentType,
                    size,
                    objectMetadata: objectMetadata,
                    format,
                }));
            });
        });

        
        const results = await Promise.all(tasks);
        const failed = results.some((result) => result.success === false);
        logs.complete();
        if (failed) {
            logs.failed();
            return;
        }
        if (originalFile) {
          logs.tempOriginalFileDeleting(filePath);
          fs.unlinkSync(originalFile);
          logs.tempOriginalFileDeleted(filePath);
        }
        const config = {
          action: 'read',
          expires: '03-01-2500',
        };
  
      const resizedImages = await Promise.all(
        results.forEach((updatedImage)=>{
        updatedImage.getSignedUrl(config);
      })); 
      console.log('Got Signed URLs.');
      const postImage = resizedImages[0];
      const feedCard = resizedImages[1];
      const zoomImage = resizedImages[2];
      const postImageUrl = postImage[0];
      const feedCardUrl = feedCard[0];
      const zoomImageUrl = zoomImage[0];   
      await admin.database().ref('feeds/{gId}/{post}').push({ postImage: postImageUrl, feedCard: feedCardUrl, zoomImage: zoomImageUrl});
      return console.log('Thumbnail URLs saved to database.');
      
    }
    catch (err) {
        logs.error(err);
    }

   // finally {

  //  }
});
```

in terminal (at project directory)
`cd functions npm install @google-cloud/storage`
package.json code

```
 {
"name": "functions",
"description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
"scripts": {
 "lint": "eslint",
 "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
 "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
 "start": "npm run shell",
 "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
 "logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"engines": {
 "node": "14"
},
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
 "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.8.5",
 "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
 "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
 "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
 "mkdirp": "^1.0.4",
 "sharp": "^0.28.3",
 " uuid": "^8.3.2",
 "uuidv4": "^6.2.11"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "eslint": "^7.6.0",
 "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
 "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
},
"private": true
}
```

I modified the nested loops a bit and still can't getSignedUrl to be found.

```
 imageTypes.forEach( async(format) => {
        imageSizes.forEach((size) => {
            tasks.push(resize_image_1.modifyImage({
                bucket,
                originalFile,
                fileDir,
                fileNameWithoutExtension,
                fileExtension,
                contentType,
                size,
                objectMetadata: objectMetadata,
                format,
            }));
        });
        const results = await Promise.all([
          remoteFile.getSignedUrl({
            action: 'read',
            expires: '03-01-2500',
          }),]);
          const config = {
            action: 'read',
            expires: '03-01-2500',
          };
          const resizedImages = await Promise.all(
            results.map((updatedImage) => updatedImage.getSignedUrl(config)));
          const postImage = resizedImages[0];
          const postImageUrl = postImage[0]; 
          await admin.database().ref('feeds/{gId}/{post}').push({ postImage: postImageUrl,});
          return console.log('Thumbnail URLs saved to database.');

    });
```

I should also mention that the images do get resized and sent to storage.
[image: Results return]

Comment: Hey, can you please `console.log(JSON.stringify(results))` before the Promise.all() and share the output here as text?

Comment: Sorry for the late response but i get this when I stringify(tasks) since I can't do results since it hasn't been created yet. [{},{},{}]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by register but using a `forEach` loop inside of `Promise.all()` won't form an array. So the problem is here:

```
const resizedImages = await Promise.all(
  results.forEach((updatedImage)=>{
  updatedImage.getSignedUrl(config);
}));
```

Instead use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) method:

```
const resizedImages = await Promise.all(
  results.map((updatedImage) => updatedImage.getSignedUrl(config))
);
```

Now the parameter in `Promise.all()` is an array.

Comment: Hi I implemented your fix and still got the same error.
Error when resizing image TypeError: updatedImage.getSignedUrl is not a function
    at /workspace/index.js:121:52
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /workspace/index.js:121:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
What I meant by not register the function was that in the index.js when I hover over getSignedUrl it's just an any. While when I pulled the repo from the project I am modifying it actually shows (method) File.getSignedUrl(cfg: GetSignedUrlConfig): Promise<GetSignedUrlResponse> etc.

Comment: @IsisCuriel can you please hover on `results` and share a screenshot of what your IDE shows about it? What's the interface of results?

Comment: The `results` array is an array of `{ size: string, success: boolean }`. `size` is the same value passed in from the `imageSizes` for loop above.

Comment: hmm that's interesting  my array is of type any while in example its this const results: [GetSignedUrlResponse, GetSignedUrlResponse]

Comment: @IsisCuriel that means `updateImage` is an array too and hence there's no getSignUrl. Let me try copying the code meanwhile can you try `console.log(updateImage[0])` and share the output?

Comment: My bet's on that it'll be `{ size: '480x480', success: true}`

Comment: @samthecodingman not sure but the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#GetSignedUrlCallback) says `GetSignedUrlResponse` should be an object containing the URL itself

Comment: While that's true, the array `results` is coming from `require('./resize-images').modifyImage(...)` in the above code. It doesn't refer to a storage `File` object at all and `getSignedUrl` would be undefined.

Comment: I also got this 
updatedImage[0] : undefined 
updatedImage[0] : undefined